# Bukkit: getInstance is null

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm currently working on an auction plugin for spigot, which is actually good

However, I keep getting this error when I start  my Minecraft server that my getInstance() method returns null. How would I fix this?
The instance is loading before anything else, as you see underneath:

```
@Override
public void onEnable() {
    instance = this;
    Objects.requireNonNull(this.getCommand("fraithorauctions")).setExecutor(mainCommand);
    eventListener.load(); //Only needs to be loaded once
    loadAll();
}
```

The error I get is pasted here: https://pastebin.com/1fQzqcU9

I posted a repository on my [github](https://github.com/Fraithor/FraithorAuctions), so you may read through it.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are initializing `instance`? The plugin should work without needing it

Answer (score 2):

It's null because you're initialising `AuctionManager` before your `onEnable()` is called.

```java
private static final AuctionManager auctionManager = new AuctionManager();
```

Your error then tells you why it being null is an issue:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.fraithor.fraithorauctions.FraithorAuctions.getDataFolder()" because the return value of "com.fraithor.fraithorauctions.FraithorAuctions.getInstance()" is null

You could simply move the initialisation to inside the `onEnable()` method like so:

```java
...
private static AuctionManager auctionManager;
...

@Override
public void onEnable() {
    instance = this;
    auctionManager = new AuctionManager();
    ...
}
```

However, it would be better practice to pass the plugin instance to your `AuctionManager` class constructor instead of relying on static fields.